# Jena infers rdfs:Resource to be in range of a owl:DatatypeProperty. Why?

Tags: java, rdf, jena, owl, reasoning

If I have any property with some XMLSchema data type in its rdfs:range, the Jena reasoner (OWL_MEM_RULE_INF spec in my case) automatically adds rdfs:Resource to that range. Why is that? Doesn't that mean I can use literally anything as a value of that property?

For example:

```
<rdf:RDF xmlns="http://mre.kiv.zcu.cz/ontology/2013/01/dasta.owl#"
    xml:base="http://mre.kiv.zcu.cz/ontology/2013/01/dasta.owl"
    xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"
    xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#"
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns:ds="http://mre.kiv.zcu.cz/ontology/2013/01/dasta.owl#">

<owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="&ds;date">
    <rdfs:label>date</rdfs:label>
    <rdfs:label xml:lang="en">date</rdfs:label>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xsd;dateTime"/>
</owl:DatatypeProperty>

</rdf:RDF>
```

Query:

```
PREFIX ds:   <http://mre.kiv.zcu.cz/ontology/2013/01/dasta.owl#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
SELECT ?r
WHERE
{
    ds:date rdfs:range ?r
}
```

Output:

```
---------------------------------------------------
| r                                               |
===================================================
| <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#dateTime>     |
| <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#Resource> |
---------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I've found out I had been misunderstanding the whole rdfs:range and rdfs:domain concept.

```
---------------------------------------------------
| r                                               |
===================================================
| <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#dateTime>     |
| <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#Resource> |
---------------------------------------------------
```

This result doesn't mean I can use anything "as a value" of the property. It means the value would be of type dateTime AND Resource -- both at once. Range of a property is meant to be an intersection (not union) of types mentioned in its rdfs:range.

Comment: This follows from [Joshua Taylor](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22973226/2528639)'s answer. Note that if you have two of the rules that JT defined in his answer (one for <code>dateTime</code> and one for <code>Resource</code>), then the implication would be that any time you saw property <code>p</code> in a statement, then the reasoner should append *both* types to the object of the statement. As every object of <code>p</code> must be both a <code>dateTime</code> and a <code>Resource</code>, then the range is the intersection.

Answer (score 2):

First, OWL_MEM_RULE_INF is an OntModelSpec that will use a reasoner that does more with OWL constructions than an OWL DL reasoners OntModelSpec.  This means that you may have some inferences that are beyond what you're expecting, but this probably isn't too much of a problem.

More to the point, though, I think you have a misunderstanding about what it means for something to be the range (or domain) of a property.  I'm basing this off of:

> the Jena reasoner… adds rdfs:Resource to that range. … Doesn't that mean I can
>   use literally anything as a value of that property?

I've written about this topic before in [this answer on answers.semanticweb.com](http://answers.semanticweb.com/questions/26463/domain-of-property-in-ontology/26464), but here's the essence of the situation. In OWL, when we say that R is a range of a property P, we mean that that whenever we see a triple whose predicate is P, we can infer that the object is an element of R.  That is, we have this inference rule:

```
X P Y      P rdfs:range R
-------------------------
    Y rdf:type R
```

If you have some property P, and P is an object property, then all the triples that have P as a predicate should have an OWL individual as an object.  Since every OWL individual is an rdfs:Resource, it's appropriate to say that rdfs:Resource is a domain of P.

Comment: Ok, I am confused now. P isn't an object property in my case and rdfs:Resource doesn't appear in it's rdfs:domain but in it's rdfs:range. So I'm not sure how this helps.

Comment: Just found the answer to my question here: http://answers.semanticweb.com/questions/14473/what-is-difference-bw-rdfsdomain-and-rdfsrange